# repeated IO on file atiumdva.cap interferes with application functionality

Tags: java, swing, windows-7, driver

Our java swing application runs on Windows 7 (32 bit) and is having some serious issues.  Our latest candidate culprit is that the system, at random intervals, performs millions of reads of 288 bytes each, on the file `c:\windows\System32\atiumdva.cap`, pegging the system at 80% CPU usage for minutes at time.

I have Googled this file and not found anything authoritative on it, just a bunch of posts from gamers about their video cards and what not.

Can someone say what this file is, who supplies it, and what it is for?  Or how to debug such an issue? My questions are programming-related to the extent that an answer to it will either inculpate/exculpate application code.

**Update:** Windows indicates that the driver that is installed is the correct and most up-to-date available. I don't think the driver is necessarily causing this. It seems more like the victim. What could cause the file to be read 288 bytes at a time, millions of times?

Could this possibly be a virus? Corporate Security is fairly intrusive about protecting its machines from viruses but possibly something's been missed? Or could the virus detection process itself cause this kind of read to happen?

Comment: Downvote because this question shows [no research effort](https://www.google.com/search?q="atiumdva.cap"). Flagged as off-topic as it is not specifically programming-related. The file is part of your ATI graphics drivers, so maybe try [Super User](http://superuser.com/) instead.

Comment: deleted and moved to main question

Comment: I removed my downvote since you updated your question to show you did *some* research. You still haven't really shown you've exercised any effort troubleshooting this: have you tried uninstalling drivers? Have you tried new drivers? Have you tried your application on another machine that doesn't have an ATI video card? Also, your post is still off-topic for StackOverflow, as the issue you are having is not directly related to programming.

Comment: Thanks.  I am in a somewhat awkward position of being a developer who is not allowed any access to the production environment.  Installing/uninstalling drivers is not normally within the purview of my responsibility.

Comment: I totally understand that, and I feel for you. I just doubt you will get the help you're looking for here, as the problems you're having aren't related to *your* code. IMO I would go up the chain with this sort of problem and express that it's an environmental issue with your production environment that cannot be directly fixed by you or your code, and that probably needs some assistance from someone who *does* have access to the environment for troubleshooting purposes.